# JSON "Invalid value around character 0" though the url works flawless and the JSON is valid

Tags: json, swift, macos, api, urlsession

I have this json error that just randomly seems to pop up.

I load json from a domain and parse it to a dictionary. If the error doesn't occur it works flawless. Here is the code:

```
func retrieveCoinPairData() {

    guard !checkIfBaseAndTargetAreEqual() else { return }

    if let base = self.currentBase, let target = self.currentTarget {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/\(base.code)-\(target.code)") {

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                if let response = response {
                    print("reponse /api/full", response)
                }
                do {
                    if let data = data {
                        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
                        self.createCoinPairData(with: jsonData)
                    } else {
                        self.delegate?.updateInfoLabelContent(content: .noInternetConnection)
                    }
                } catch {
                    self.delegate?.updateInfoLabelContent(content: .error)
                    print("catch error", error, data?.description as Any)
                    self.retrieveCoinPairData()
                }
            }).resume()
        } else {
            self.delegate?.updateInfoLabelContent(content: .error)
        }
    }
}
```

The server response is the following throwing an 403 error:

```
reponse /api/full <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000232400> { 
URL: https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/BTC-ETH } { 
status code: 403, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 05 Jun 2018 04:23:37 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15";
    Server = nginx;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identit
```

and the URLSession catch error is the following:

```
catch error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 
"Invalid value around character 0." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
Optional("162 bytes")
```

The error occurs in the `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]` line.

Now anytime this error occurs (and it is completely random), when I check the url in the browser it works perfect.

I checked the json with jsonlint.com and it is valid, there is no top level object that makes the json need fragmentation, though that option seemed to reduce the error in the past.

I know the code 403 error tells me the website blocks access and the code 3840 error tells me there is no content to be parsed. Still I wonder where and why the error occurs.

This is the site used in this example: https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/btc-eth

Comment: I suspect you're not getting valid json back from the server in the case of a `403` error (and instead you're getting a plain text error response).  You can print out the data *before* you try to deserialize it by using `print("\(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))")`.

Comment: thank you. it prints "<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n" so yes you are right. any idea what might lead to this? is this even in my power? the thing that bugs me is that the url works anytime when i manually open it in browser

Comment: Unrelated but as always, the option `.allowFragments` is pointless if the expected type is a collection type. Omit the `options` parameter. To solve the issue handle the response code.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: so i contacted them and they said the website would automatically ban the ip (for some short time) if it surpasses 100 calls/minute. makes sense though i wouldnt say my app comes even near to that through testing. waiting for another answer from them.

Answer (score 0):

Change your lines of code to do this:

```
if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
 }
 if let httpResponse = response as HTTPURLResponse {
    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
         // do your json deserialization after you verify you 
         // got a 200 / OK from the server
         do {
            if let data = data {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
                self.createCoinPairData(with: jsonData)
            } else {
                self.delegate?.updateInfoLabelContent(content: .noInternetConnection)
            }
        } catch {
            self.delegate?.updateInfoLabelContent(content: .error)
            print("catch error", error, data?.description as Any)
            self.retrieveCoinPairData()
        }
    } else {
        print("reponse /api/full", response)
    }
 }
```

And what you see there is that you should only attempt JSON deserialization if you know the server sent you a 200/OK response.

Comment: thank you. still throwing: reponse /api/full Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000424c80> { URL: https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/BTC-ETH } { status code: 403, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 05 Jun 2018 05:00:02 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15";
    Server = nginx;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }) still, my problem is that somewhere between my code and the **working** url something goes wrong and i dont know what it is

Comment: Can you point to where you found the `https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full` endpoint?  I'm looking at the API documentation for cryptonator.com and I don't see `full` in the API anywhere.

Comment: https://www.cryptonator.com/api its right there under "complete ticker". i hope that anwers ayour question?

Answer (score 0):

There is a redirection on the url which occure sometime. You can see redirecting something like ohio.something sometime you request the url. 
When the redirection happen, urlsession get the error code 403. 
And also invalide value around 0 occure when json serialisation get html or other code than vald json object.

Try to remove the redirection from the webservice.

Comment: okay thank you. i understand how the html creates the 3840 error. what do you mean by "remove the redirection"? how am i supposed to do that?

Comment: According to [this Apple developer forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26662), "you have no need to handle redirection by yourself. NSURLSession and its tasks will do it appropriately, including cookie handling".  This makes it sound like the remote server isn't providing a valid site to redirect to.

Comment: i just emailed them, maybe they have an answer. and i think the redirection might really be the problem. calling the url right now i do not get redirected and running the app at the same time doesnt throw an error. now im waiting for them to redirect me (in browser) and if the app crashes that should identify the error at least.

Comment: you cannot remove or handle the redirection. this suppose to be done on server end.

Comment: so i contacted them and they said the website would automatically ban the ip (for some short time) if it surpasses 100 calls/minute. makes sense though i wouldnt say my app comes even near to that through testing. waiting for another answer from them.

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be like this, this is just demo version you have to modify it accordingly as per your requirement,

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/BTC-ETH") {
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "get"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error ?? "")
            return
        }
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultResponse.self, from: data)
            print(response)
        } catch {
            print("catch error", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }.resume()
} else {
    //Your else code
}
```

Below are two Codable classes,

```
struct Ticker: Codable {
    let base, target, price, volume: String
    let change: String
    let markets: [String]
}

struct ResultResponse: Codable {
    let ticker: Ticker
    let timestamp: Int
    let success: Bool
    let error: String
}
```

Once you call this, you will get following output,

```
ResultResponse(ticker: Demo.Ticker(base: "BTC", target: "ETH", price: "12.67485919", volume: "", change: "-0.04568160", markets: []), timestamp: 1528180081, success: true, error: "")
```